# Avoid OpenERP audittrail bug

Tags: python, audit-trail, odoo

I'd like to manage OpenERP user's activity by installing the audittrail module.
After creating some rules ( define which user, which object and which activity (create, update..) will be monitored).  I update a product to see it works.
When I've tried to update a product i got the system error. Seeing the log, I get
*[2010-08-31 12:53:35,042]  Cursor not closed explicitly

[2010-08-31 12:53:35,043]  Cursor was created at /home/pilgrim/working/sources/addons/audittrail/audittrail.py:204*
Here the line that causes error
          cr = pooler.get_db(db).cursor()
Looking at sql_db.py, I get the comment

```
def __del__(self):
    if not self.__closed:
        # Oops. 'self' has not been closed explicitly.
        # The cursor will be deleted by the garbage collector,
        # but the database connection is not put back into the connection
        # pool, preventing some operation on the database like dropping it.
        # This can also lead to a server overload.
        msg = "Cursor not closed explicitly\n"  \
              "Cursor was created at %s:%s" % self.__caller
        log(msg, netsvc.LOG_WARNING)
        self.close()
```

Since I'm new to Python, I don't know how to overcome this issue?
Any hint to get over this?
Thank

Comment: Warning will be raised only in the case where you've opened the cursor explicitly by yourself and forgot to close it after performing your logic, you need to call cr.close() before cr gets out of its scope....

Answer (score 5):

t would be important to see the source code to understand whats going on.
But from what you have posted it looks like the previous cursor was not closed explicitly.

```
cr = sqldb.db_connect(dbname).cursor()
.........
cr.close()
cr = None
```

I would suggest that you hack audittrail.py to find where ever you are creating the cursor and where ever you close them. A typical issue arises in incorrect handling of exceptions, causing code to jump over normal closure.

Try placing a try, except and finally clause around the questionable cursor operation. That should help you to get around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think I find the answer. 
See an example

```
def a():  
  try:
    print 'before return '
    return 1
  finally:
    print 'in finally'
```

call a()

```
before return 
in finally
1
```

It's normal. OK.
Try another example ( code extract from audittrail.py)

```
def do_something_with_db(db):
   // open cusror again
   cr = db.cursor()
   // do somethign
   // close cursor internally
   cr.close()
def execute(db)
   // 1, open connection and open cursor
   cr = db.cursor
   try:
        //2, do something with db, seeing that this method will open cursor again
       return do_something_with_db(db)
   finally:
       cr.close()
```

Seeing that the implementation of do_something_with_db trying to open the cursor ( can be called connection) but the current one is not explicitly closed.
So the solution is simple: Pass the current cr around

```
Before
**do_something_with_db(db)**
after
**do_something_with_db(cr)**
```

Now the error's gone.

@Don Kirkby: Yes, we should experiment with try...finally

Answer (score 1):

Can you run OpenERP in a debugger like the [PyDev plug in](http://pydev.org/) for [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)? I find that the most effective way to track down problems. I haven't used the audit trail module, but I took a quick look at the [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/5.0/annotate/head:/audittrail/audittrail.py), and it appears that the cursor is being opened near the beginning of `log_fct()`. (I would have expected it to report line 207, which version are you running?) Here's what I think is the relevant code:

```
def log_fct(self, db, uid, passwd, object, method, fct_src, *args):
    logged_uids = []
    pool = pooler.get_pool(db)
    cr = pooler.get_db(db).cursor() # line 207 in version 5.0.12

    # ...

    if method in ('create'):

        # ...

        cr.close()
        return res_id

    # ...

    cr.close()
```

It looks like there are several return statements in the method, but each one seems to call `cr.close()` first, so I don't see any obvious problems. Try running it in the debugger with a break point in this method. If that's not possible, you can try writing to the log with something like this:

```
    logger = netsvc.Logger()
    logger.notifyChannel('audittrail', netsvc.LOG_INFO, 'something happened')
```

**Update:**
You commented that this happens under heavy load. Perhaps an exception is being thrown and the cursor is not being closed. You could use a `try` ... `finally` [statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) to make sure that the cursor is *always* closed. Here's how the sample above would look after converting it:

```
def log_fct(self, db, uid, passwd, object, method, fct_src, *args):
    logged_uids = []
    pool = pooler.get_pool(db)
    cr = pooler.get_db(db).cursor() # line 207 in version 5.0.12
    try:

        # ...

        if method in ('create'):

            # ...

            return res_id

        # ...

    finally:
        cr.close()
```

Comment: I did quickly look at the source code and haven't seen any obvious problems. We've got the problem in production environment where many users do many things and this issue leads to db out of connection. I should simulate stress tests to see how thing works.
Note: I'm using Pydev but found nothing.
Thank you for your answering.

Comment: You're welcome, @lapilgrim. I added another suggestion to experiment with try...finally.